# Cannot install Stremio in Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, package-management

I have downloaded the `stremio` installation file from this [website](https://www.stremio.com/). On unpacking the `.deb` file (in Ubuntu 20.10 64 bit machine) it gives the following error:

```
Unpacking stremio (4.4.116-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of stremio:
 stremio depends on nodejs; however:
  Package nodejs is not installed.
 stremio depends on qml-module-qt-labs-platform (>= 5.9.5); however:
  Package qml-module-qt-labs-platform is not installed.
 stremio depends on qml-module-qtwebchannel (>= 5.9.5); however:
  Package qml-module-qtwebchannel is not installed.
 stremio depends on qml-module-qtwebengine (>= 5.9.5); however:
  Package qml-module-qtwebengine is not installed.
 stremio depends on libfdk-aac1 (>= 0.1.5); however:
  Package libfdk-aac1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package stremio (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 stremio
```

To resolve the error or fix the missing dependencies, I ran the command `sudo apt -f install`. However this command does nothing other than just uninstalling the broken `stremio` installation.

Please help.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this bro, works for me

```
wget https://dl.strem.io/shell-linux/v4.4.116/stremio_4.4.116-1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/f/fdk-aac/libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb 
sudo dpkg -i libfdk-aac1_0.1.5-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./stremio_4.4.116-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked.

Comment: Thanks for indicating the source for libfdk-aac1 package which is no longer in the official repos, but you can remove or modify the first and last lines as it works with the later stremio versions as well.

Comment: Confirmed it's working in debian testing 11, but in addition you must install libx264.so.152 from ubuntu repository